# how to call the p-table OnRowSelect(event) function from the button click function of the same p-table in Angular

Tags: angular

```
I'm trying to call onRowSelect(event) while clicking the action button of p-table without rewrite the same code.
```

Html code is

```
<p-table [value]="list" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)">
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button (click)="clickEvent(row)"> </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

p-table onRowselect function

```
    onRowSelect(event) 
    {
    //code
    }
```

button click function

```
clickEvent(value:any)
        {                      
       //code
        }
```

I want to call onRowSelect inside the clickEvent function without rewrite the code of onRowSelect

Answer (score 0):

you should pass $event in your click event like

```
(click)="clickEvent($event)
```

and check if it is clicked event, in clickEvent function call onRowSelect passing the same event like

```
clickEvent(value:any)
        {                      
       //if click event or rowSelect event
this.onRowSelect(value);
        }
```

Comment: I tried it's not working for me, i can't get the particular row value in the clickEvent method.

Comment: if you want particular row value in clickEvent, you need to do vice-versa, that means call a same onRowSelect method on button click and in ts file call clickEvent function in onRowselect function according to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `$event` in your click event

```
<tr (click)="clickEvent(row)">
    <td>
       <button (click)="clickEvent(row)">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData" (click)="selectRow(rowData)">
        {{rowData.name}}
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

This worked for me on verion 9.x.